# cURL analog in C#?

Tags: c#, linux, curl

trying to send the request but it doesn't work for some reason:

This is what should work with CURL command

```
curl --data "client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}" https://cloud.testtest.com/oauth/access_token.php
```

But in C# I've built this one:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://cloud.merchantos.com/oauth/access_token.php");
webRequest.Method = "POST";

    if (requestBody != null)
    {
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write("client_id=1&client_secret=111&code=MY_CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=app.testtest.com");
        }
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException exception)
    {
        var responseStream = exception.Response.GetResponseStream();
        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            throw new WebException(text);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Please advice. for some reason can't figure out why the code doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify the "doesn't work".

Comment: I suppose the code which I written doesn't work because I receive from the server that 400 bad request. Sounds like I made a mistake in the C# code

Comment: You need to read the response from the server, it should be giving you a Json formatted error description. If I use the details you specify (obviously you have changed the credentials) it give a HTTP 400 error with this: `error_description=The client credentials are invalid`

Comment: yeah. I am thinking can it be because of incorrect content type or so? They have example only with curl tool but not with C#. Hard to understand how it should work:
http://www.lightspeedretail.com/cloud/help/developers/api/oauth/

Here is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Get the response body and post the results here, without that we cannot tell what the problem is.

Comment: Uploaded as an image the response

Comment: But the credentials are valid.

Comment: Maybe I need to encrypt the post data somehow?

Comment: Does it work when you use cUrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `WebRequest` you need to follow a certain pattern, by setting the request types, credentials, and the request content if any.

This usually comes out to something like:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
// Set the Network credentials
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

The above is a sample of how the request should be constructed.  Reviewing your sample code, it appears you are missing the `Credentials` and the `ContentLength` properties.  The exception screenshot indicates a problem with the former however.

See more details on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t38832a(v=vs.110).aspx